# Timer that can interact with context.object?

Tags: python, scripting

i'd like to create a timer that can interract with the active object.
every time the active object is not the same as the object in my pointer prop it automatically replace pointer object with the active object.

i don't understand why they restric us doing this kind of things. 
how can i achieve something similar ?

```
class SCATTER_OT_terrain_is_active(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scatter.terrain_is_active"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = "Constantly use the active object as Terrain"

    def execute(self, context):
        addon_prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        C_Slots     = bpy.context.scene.C_Slots_settings

        addon_prefs.active_is_terrain = not addon_prefs.active_is_terrain

        if addon_prefs.active_is_terrain == True:
            print("start timer")
            bpy.app.timers.register(check_active)
        else: print("stop timer")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def check_active():
    addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
    C_Slots     = bpy.context.scene.C_Slots_settings
    Active      = bpy.context.object

    print("check")
    if addon_prefs.active_is_terrain == False:
        return None

    if Active != C_Slots.Terrain_pointer:
        C_Slots.Terrain_pointer = Active
    return 0.65
```

Comment: Can you please clarify: "...it automatically replace the new one and add the new one." - what automatically replaces what and adds what to what?

Comment: sorry, mispells

Answer (score -1):

with a handler it may work

```
import bpy, os

ao = None

def h(s):
    # just for testing, normally i won't use global
    global ao
    o = bpy.context.active_object
    if(ao != o):
        ao = o
        print(ao)
    if ao.name == "Cam Small":
        return None

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(h)
```

but that doesn't really respond to the goal of the question

Comment: Remember  the argument of handlers is the scene. (except load where it is  value `None` dummy)  For a  handler defined  `def handler(scene):`.  the active object is `scene.objects.active`  Your pointer is `scene.C_slots.Terrain_pointer`  which can be tested against for change without using the global (otherwise changing scenes will most likely flag a change to global).  Re your OP, the `context` reference is lost to the timer thread. Could pass the scene to a partial and use that as timer method (see timer example in docs)  IMO if you wish to do something on change in user UI a modal timer

Comment: operator is the go. (see example in text editor python script templates) Give the user the option to invoke it with button or boolean, to turn it on or off.